# How to use awk to count the total number of input lines in a file?

Tags: awk

How can I use awk to count the total number of input lines in a file?

Comment: It's worth you putting some detail each time about what you've tried so far.  Otherwise people might look at your previous questions and just think you're getting your homework done for you ;-)  https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/221298/tcsasyla

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The special variable `NR` holds the current line number. Once the entire file has been processed, it will hold the total number of lines of that file. So, you can do:

```
awk 'END{print NR}' file
```

Of course, that is a bit silly when there's a program designed specifically for this:

```
wc -l file
```

Comment: Not silly to avoid `wc` because `date $'+%Y\n%m\n%d'>file; wc -l file` outputs `>       3 file`. (with the spaces on macOS/BSD, without them on GNU). if you are going to have to `awk` the integer out anyway…

Comment: @BrunoBronosky try `wc -l < file` instead. Or `cat file | wc -l`.

Comment: That works for GNU, but on macOS/BSD, the spaces are still there. `echo "#$(date $'+%Y\n%m\n%d' | wc -l)#"`
returns `#       3#` #SMH

Comment: @BrunoBronosky huh. Thanks, I didn't realize that wasn't portable behavior.

Comment: `wc -l` counts the number of NEWLINE characters, not necessarily the number of lines.  I prefer `awk`

Comment: @Kajukenbo lines are defined by newline characters, how else? Counting the number of lines means counting the number of newline characters.

Comment: @terdon It is not unheard of to have a line of text without a NL at the end.  That is one reason many old-school Unix peeps say to be sure to have a Blank Line at the end of a file (like old /etc/hosts).  That ensures there is NL at the end of the last "text" line.

Comment: @Kajukenbo if it doesn't have a newline, it isn't a line. They say you need to leave a blank line at the end because that's the POSIX definition of a text file.

Comment: Some of `awk` versions like `Solaris` one have record too long Error use `gawk` instead.

Answer (score 3):

To count the total number of input lines in a file with `awk`:

```
awk 'END{ print NR }' input.data
```

Or with `sed`:

```
sed -n \$= input.data
```